# Sitemaps for country domains which are directories

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt

We have a global client who has five country sites-

```
domain.com/us/
domain.com/uk/
domain.com/de/
```

..

We have setup sitemap.xml files inside each folder.

```
domain.com/us/sitemap-us.xml
domain.com/uk/sitemap-uk.xml
domain.com/de/sitemap-de.xml
```

..

Now, will Google pick up these automatically inside each folder, or do we have to specify each sitemap inside the parent `robots.txt`? I ask because apparently, based on [Google help](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?csw=1), robots.txt can only be in the parent domain, once. So even if we put a robots.txt file inside each country's folder, it's useless -- the respective sitemap won't be picked up.

How should we specify Google to pick it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should gather all your sitemaps into a single *.XML* file, and then submit it to the Google Webmaster Tools. If you wish your sitemap to be indexed by other SE (w/o manual submitting), then name your XML sitemap as *sitemap.xml* and place it to the site's root, e.g.: *site.com/sitemap.xml*